# AT&T installed 2Wire cable modem/G-class router. Need to link that to my DGN2000 (N-Class) router ASAP

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Router in office: NetGear DGN2000 (2 of 4 transceivers used) 802.11N
Router at cable intake: 2Wire 3800HGV

Goal: Link the two routers (preferably via wired connection) and use the Netgear for its better range

Difficulty: I'm a computer tech, and other than suspecting I'll have to reroute an existing Cat5E cable (or strip it out and go Cat6) I'm not entirely sure how to best go about this.

To be honest, it may be easier in the long run to find a way to replace the 2Wire unit with a N-compliant router or find some way to accept the VDSL signal with a custom-built router-rig, but that's a bit more $$$ than I currently have the capability of spending. (Besides, if we can figure out how to properly do what I'm asking, costs will be minimal, and speed of the network will be much better and closer to the VDSL upload/download limits.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get a [cheap @$$ cable modem](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=cable+modem&x=0&y=0) (~$40 for a new one, ~$20 for a used one, or whatever you can find on eBay) and skip the AT&T modem/router altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Just connect them with an ethernet cable.  If theres no link light then it doesn't support Auto MDIX.  In that case you'll have to either connect them with a crossover cable or hook one of them into the 'uplink' (or similarly named) port.